# Can not install antivirus because of microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 conflict

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, .net-framework

I have recently updated my os to windows 10.
When I tried to install kesperysky antivirus it shows that microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 is not installed in your computer that is why the antivirus can not be installed.
Whenever I install the microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 a message appears saying that the the software is already installed in my pc, but when I go into programs and features in control panel there is no any microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 in the program installed list.
Because of this problem i am unable to install any antivirus.
What should i do?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.5.1 is installed by default on Windows 10.  If it's not installed then the Windows Feature was removed

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 actually has .NET 4.6 installed (which should be compatible with proper versions of .NET 4).  See this article:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2015/06/17/a-couple-of-notes-about-net-framework-4-6-setup-behaviors/

"If you run into an application compatibility issue with the .NET Framework 4 family on Windows 10, you cannot revert back to an earlier version of the .NET Framework 4 family by using the uninstall and re-install instructions that I listed above like you can on older versions of Windows.  In that scenario, I typically recommend contacting the application manufacturer to see if they have any patches available that will allow their application to install and run with the .NET Framework 4.6 installed."

Kaspersky's site seems to have acknowledged this problem and has provided Windows 10 compatible versions of its products: https://usa.kaspersky.com/windows10